# Cannot Open my FTP server (FTP Folder Error)

Tags: windows-7, ftp

Thanks for reading :)
First of all let me describe basics things.

FTP Server from : 2freehosting.com

FTP Site : fliq.2fh.co

FTP IP : 31.170.167.141

Windows 7 x64

I always get this error http://goo.gl/9LIy7k when I try to open FTP server via Windows explorer. I also tried to open FTP server via Internet Explorer and FileZilla, but I couldn't open it. Please help me.
I've also allowed FTP in firewall.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you open both FTP ports in the firewall?

Comment: Yes. I checked both

Answer (score 0):

Did you check ports used by FTP. Port 20-21 are for FTP and could be closed on your PC. You can download PortQRY.exe from Microsoft to help with your FTP problem.

Comment: I download PortQRY.exe

Comment: I downlaoded PortQRY.exe     when I run it, it opens a window,then close it after 1-2 secs